# htaccess redirect to index.php ignore every other php file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want every url or file to be redirected to index.php but some exceptions(see below). It worked fine on my local server but on the real server it doesn't work like it should.

My problem is that there are files like collection.php that are opened when I type that into the browsers url and ignored by my htacess. These files are supposed to be redirected to my index.php as well. What can I do?

My htaccess:

```
# html5 pushstate (history) support:

AddHandler php5-cgi .php

AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /WALT/

#rewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/content/create/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/img/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/video/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/favicon.ico [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/cms/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/collection.php [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]

</ifModule>
```

Comment: Is this being used in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/WALT` directory?

Comment: And what URL isn't working as expected?

Comment: well every url is redirected to index.php except the files that are real / existing php files. those are not redirected.

Comment: I understand the intent but you must be testing with URLs right? e.g. `http://sit.com/WALT/foo` OR `http://sit.com/WALT/collection.php`

Comment: well I discovered what my problem is. I used ajax to load the same files i was redirecting in my htaccess. so it all made no sense. I moved all views / pages except index.php into a subfolder called views. and now I don't have any redirecting problems anymore with my pushstate by using the htaccess you gave me in an earlier post. thank you very much again.

Comment: Glad to know your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your Apache (or other Webserver) config. In the ConfigFile, where the VHOSTs are declared, be sure, that "AllowOverwrite" is set to "ALL"

Best way to debug is to activate RewriteLogs temporary. So you see where the error may be.

Comment: Don't you mean `AllowOverride` instead of AllowOverwrite?

Comment: thanks, I don't think I have access to anything else but I'll have a look. the support guy from the domain said it's because of RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f because this checks if a file doesn't exist. but the collection.php exists so that's why it doesn't work. If I leave it out then it doesn't work at all